# Why aren't any dev libraries found when node_modules included in volumes?

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, node-modules, babeljs, docker-volume

When I try to start my node project with `docker-compose`, I always get the error

```
sh: babel-node: not found
[nodemon] failed to start process, "babel-node" exec not found
```

```
  app-1:
    build: src/app-1
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    volumes:
      - ./src/app-1:/usr/src/app
      - app-1-build:/usr/src/app/build
      - app-1-modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: npm run dev
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
```

However when I commend out `- app-1-modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules` it works fine, but raises another error which I won't bring up in this question. Why is it that when I include the node_module in the volume it is not able to find the babel libraries. I have these installed:

```
"@babel/cli",
"@babel/core",
"@babel/node",
"@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
"@babel/preset-env",
"@babel/preset-typescript",
```

Comment: can you share your docker file ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your application's dependencies aren't being installed correctly.
Without having seen neither your package.json nor your Dockerfile, **you can try this**:

1. Add `RUN npm install` to your Dockerfile.
2. You should run nodemon with `npx` so it can use your local dependencies. Modify your `npm run dev` script so it looks like this:

```
npx nodemon --exec "babel-node server.js"
```

3. Make sure to list the named volumes being used at the bottom of your docker-compose file, like so:

```
volumes:
  app-1-modules
  app-1-build
```

Please let me know if this answer was helpful to you!